# PHP Can't change json data in array

Tags: php, arrays, json

I'm working on a socket server for a game I'm working on but I'm having issues changing some data which was decoded from json.

I have a function called decodeCrumbs which fetches the "crumbs" or the user data from the database, json_decodes it and puts it into an array. This works fine but after this I'm unable to change any of the array data.

```
    $query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE username='".$this->username."';", $this->db);
    $row = mysql_fetch_array($query);
    $crumbs = json_decode($row['crumbs'], true);
    $this->crumbs = $crumbs;
    $this->crumbs["roomFurniture"] = "This does not work";
```

echoing `$this->crumbs["roomFurniture"] returns ""` which is the default ( from the json data ) I've also tried using var_dump but that also confirms it has not changed. I also tried adding `public $crumbs` at the beginning of the class but it still happens

I have no idea what is causing this or how to fix it

Var_dump of $this->crumbs

```
array(24) {
  ["id"]=>
  int(1)
  ["nickname"]=>
  string(7) "Default"
  ["email"]=>
  string(0) ""
  ["active"]=>
  int(1)
  ["ban"]=>
  int(0)
  ["ismod"]=>
  int(0)
  ["rank"]=>
  int(0)
  ["key"]=>
  string(0) ""
  ["head"]=>
  int(0)
  ["face"]=>
  int(0)
  ["neck"]=>
  int(0)
  ["body"]=>
  int(0)
  ["hands"]=>
  int(0)
  ["feet"]=>
  int(0)
  ["photo"]=>
  int(0)
  ["flag"]=>
  int(0)
  ["colour"]=>
  int(1)
  ["items"]=>
  array(2) {
    [0]=>
    int(413)
    [1]=>
    int(1)
  }
  ["buddies"]=>
  array(0) {
  }
  ["ignore"]=>
  array(0) {
  }
  ["joindate"]=>
  string(0) ""
  ["coins"]=>
  int(1000)
  ["furniture"]=>
  array(0) {
  }
  ["roomFurniture"]=>
  string(0) ""
}
```

Comment: You have to update the values in the database table.

Comment: The `crumbs` from the DB are in JSON format?

Comment: @HenriqueBarcelos Why should OP do it?

Comment: The crumbs are only read once from the database so I have no need to save them right now, I can't even change it so there would be no point in saving it. @ Henrique. And yes, they are in json format in the database.

Comment: `var_dump($this->crumbs);`

Comment: Added var_dump of $this->crumbs

Comment: If this function is indeed in a class and you have instantiated it as an object, then it would be an issue of where later you are echoing or var_dumping `$this->crumbs["roomFurniture"]`

Comment: @user2601312 The key `roomFurniture` is empty string. Its working as expected. Try echoing `$this->crumbs["nickname"]` you will the result

Comment: json_decode is set to true to return an array if thats what you mean @ abra. @rahil, the var_dump was after $this->crumbs["roomFurniture"] = "This does not work";. It should of been "This does not work" but instead is ""

Comment: I have a feeling that your code is not executing in the order that you think it is. I tested this code: `<?php

class MyClass {

    public function someFunction()
    {
        $crumbs = '{"id":1,"nickname":"Default","email":"","roomFurniture":""}';
        $this->crumbs = json_decode($crumbs, true);
        $this->crumbs["roomFurniture"] = "This does not work";
        echo $this->crumbs["roomFurniture"]."\n";
    }
}

$myclass = new MyClass();
$myclass->someFunction();
?>` and the output was `This does not work`.

Comment: Could you post the whole class file?